# Pixelated text after writing on image with CGContextShowTextAtPoint

Tags: ios, cgcontext

I'm writing on an image using:

```
float shadowColorValues[] = {0, 0, 0, .3};
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake (2, -2), 3 * imageScale, shadowColor);

CGContextSelectFont(context, newFontName, fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, textX, textY, newText, strlen(newText));
```

If I'm using a font like Chalkduster the result is very pixelated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/heGu1.png. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your context has probably not the right screen scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
 CGSize size,
 BOOL opaque,
 CGFloat scale // pass 0 for screen scale
);
```

when creating the image context.